Share my music library between MacOS and Ubuntu
Is it possible somehow to have a virgin partition where my music library (60gb+) would be stored, and on one side macos with iTunes accessing in real time this library (I want to keep it because I have an iPod), and the other hand Ubuntu with Lollypop or Rhythmbox that access the same music on the music partition ? And I'd like it to be updated on both: if I add an album while on Ubuntu, well i'd put it in the music partition so I expect it to show up in iTunes on the macOS partition as well.
I hope this is clear because its not so easy to me in english.
Thanks !

From what I understand you have a dual-boot setup with two systems: Ubuntu and Mac OS.
In that case yes, sharing a partition between the two systems is easy. You just need to format it with a file-system that can be visible from both systems. From some googling it seems UDF, FAT32 and HFS+ are supported by both Linux and Mac OS, so you can use one of them.
With that out of the way, it should just work: if you put some files to the partition while being on Mac OS, you'll see it once you boot Ubuntu and vice versa. You'd probably also want to add an /etc/fstab entry for that partition to make sure it's auto-mounted on boot.
You'd probably also want to use some music player that works on both systems and configure it in such a way so it would keep its settings on the partition. This way whatever changes you do from one system that are specific to the player, they will be seen on the other system as well. For example, Amarok is a good player that is supported on both Linux and Mac OS (for Ubuntu you can install it from the repo).

Thank you, this is exactly what I meant. I think Im gonna try this. I know how to automatically mount the partition from the start on Ubuntu, not so sure with macOS, maybe its automatic ? idk.
Im still gonna use iTunes though, because my concern here is being able to update my iPod and transfer songs, so I'm just hoping iTunes can deal with this. Otherwise I might have to stick with my outdated laggy macOS. Anyway thank you very much !
